# React library not working when project deployed to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vercel

I created a project with ReactJS, and one of the components uses the `react-countup` library. When I run the app on localhost it works perfectly fine. But as soon as I deployed the app to Vercel the library doesn't work anymore:

Code of the components:

```
import React from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";

const Stats = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex mt-32 justify-center" id="stats">
      <div className="flex flex-col rounded-3xl p-10 md:flex-row gap-28 lg:pt-24 lg:pb-24 lg:pl-36 lg:pr-36 lg:bg-bgStats lg:bg-no-repeat lg:bg-contain">
        <CountUp start={0} end={200000} duration={1.5}>
          {({ countUpRef }) => (
            <div className="flex flex-col text-center ">
              <span ref={countUpRef} className="text-5xl text-sky-500" />
              <span className="text-gray-400 text-2xl"> Users</span>
            </div>
          )}
        </CountUp>
        <CountUp start={0} end={300} duration={1.5} prefix="$" suffix="M">
          {({ countUpRef }) => (
            <div className="flex flex-col text-center">
              <span ref={countUpRef} className="text-5xl text-green-500" />
              <span className="text-gray-400 text-2xl"> Total Value</span>
            </div>
          )}
        </CountUp>
        <CountUp start={0} end={250} duration={1.5} suffix="+">
          {({ countUpRef }) => (
            <div className="flex flex-col text-center ">
              <span ref={countUpRef} className="text-5xl text-orange-600" />
              <span className="text-gray-400 text-2xl"> Investors</span>
            </div>
          )}
        </CountUp>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stats;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dex",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-countup": "^6.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
    "react-spring": "^9.7.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

If you have any suggestion please let me know.